# Estimating a sum over prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

At page 3 of this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03755.pdf about the new proof of Halasz's Theorem, the authors claim that $$\sum\limits_{(\log x)^4< p\leq x/2}\frac{\log p}{p\log(x/p)}\ll\log\log x.$$ It should be equivalent to $$\sum\limits_{(\log x)^4< p\leq x/2}\frac1{p\log(x/p)}\ll\frac{\log\log x}{\log x}.$$

I know how to prove the bounds if $p$ runs up to a fixed power of $x$, but not all the way up to $x/2$.

Thank you.

Comment: Cross-posted from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2679534

Comment: Is it forbidden?

Comment: Simultaneous cross-posting is quite frowned upon, as it leads to duplication of effort. Each community should have a honest shot at the question. The acceptable way is to cross post only after a significant amount of time (at least several days) passed without a useful answer. And in any case, it is an absolute must to provide links in both directions.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I first posted it to stack.exchange but then found out that it would be more appropriate for mathoverflow. I will join the links to both questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the fact that

$$\sum_{y\leq p\leq 2y} \frac{\log p}{p}\ll 1,$$

we get for any $A\geq 2$

$$\sum_{x/2A\leq p\leq x/A} \frac{\log p}{p\log(x/p)}\ll \frac{1}{\log A}$$

Hence for any positive integer $l$ we have

$$\sum_{x/2^{l+1}\leq p\leq x/2^l} \frac{\log p}{p\log(x/p)}\ll \frac{1}{l}.$$

Summing this over all $l$ with $2\leq 2^l\leq x$ we get

$$\sum_{ p\leq x/2} \frac{\log p}{p\log(x/p)}\ll \sum_{0\lt l\leq \log x} \frac{1}{l} \ll \log\log x,$$

as needed.